# Assign unique permision on the Page level

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, 2013, permissions, publishing-site

I have the following inside my publishing site:-

1. 5 enterprise Wikis sub sites.
2. For each sub-site I have defined unique security groups on who can read, contribute, have full control on each such sub site.

But currently I need to grant certain authenticated customers the permsion to only view specific Wiki articles pages, so I follow these steps:-

- Go to the desired wiki page.
- Click on Edit.
- Go to “Page permission”

But I was redirected to the subsite permission groups , so if I define a new restricted read group and I assign the external customer to it, then the external customer will have restricted-read permission on all the sub site articles which I want to avoid, as I need him to only read specific Wiki page.

Second problem I am facing is that to be able to create new group on the sub site or page level, I have to stop inheriting permissions from parent site. So why I cannot create new group at the sub site level or at the document level unless I stop inheriting permissions from parent site?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure on what your exact problem is. When I change the permission for only one page in my Wiki it only effects that one page. Stop inheriting from the parent and then Grant Permissions to your new user/group for Read or View Only. That should be all you have to do. No other pages should be impacted by this change. If this isn't working for you can you list step by step what you do and what the results are?

Also, have you tried creating a few dummy pages and playing around with the permissions to really get an idea of how the security is handled? This is what I did when first assigned to our wiki's development through SP Enterprise Wiki.